# putting blog posts under version control

Tags: svn, version-control, blogging

Is there any way to version control blog posts? I don't mind running subversion on my server, but I want my buddies to make changes to what I write and commit to svn, then update the blog post. Has anyone done this? Or is there any other solution for this problem?

Comment: What software are you using for your blog?  Some software puts the post content in database tables, other software puts it in files.

Comment: I am writing on wordpress.com. Thought about having many people edit some post and commit those changes to some version control system. Thanks

Comment: What blogging software are you using? Some, like WordPress include version control already.

Comment: wordpress.com blog

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you are running your own web server you may want to take a look at some of the CMS systems available.

The one I have in mind in particular is [Drupal](http://www.drupal.org) which I know has modules available for blogging and built-in version control.  It also does an awful lot more than just blogging.

Comment: A CMS would seem a better approach to this problem.

Answer (score 1):

[Nanoc](http://nanoc.stoneship.org/) is a static site generator that can be used with version control. It is currently used for quite a few small sites and blogs. I am currently using it for a few of the sites I have done because it is so easy to use once it is setup.

Answer (score 1):

Ikiwiki lists this as the first of [its features](http://ikiwiki.info/features/).  I'm using it for my notes for exactly this reason - I've been keeping my notes as random text and HTML files in my repository for years, now I have a web front end that interacts seamlessly with all that history.

The disadvantage of Ikiwiki is that it's obsessed with simplicity of design, to the detriment of simplicity of use.  Basically, it's a geekfest, which I hate.  So I hesitate to actually recommend it...